# Can we implement gateways for sending sms in node js , Any alternate for KANNEL?

Tags: node.js, sms, kannel

Wants to create sms service how to implement gateways in nodejs other than using kannel,
Any opensource Alternates for kannel method

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can implement an SMS-Gateway in any language. While on the north part you can implement the protocol you want (XML, JSON, whatever on HTTP(S), or messaging queues, or even your own), on one south part, the one that connects to the telco network you need to talk to the SMSC which usually talks [SMPP 3.4](https://smpp.org/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) and implementing SMPP might be tricky.

Kannel had been around for something like 20 years and I would say it had been battle tested since then. We are using it and I can't remember any single problem due to Kannel since ever.

[JasminSMS](https://www.jasminsms.com/) is an often cited alternative but I never played with it. There are some others, just google for *opensource sms gateway*.

Comment: By curiosity, why would you like to ***implement*** an SMS-Gateway your self ?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your needs for the SMS Gateway features ,there 2 alternative to kannel :  playsms and jasmin SMS gateway   , keep  in mind you still need to have an outgoing route connected to  your sms gateway to send the sms out to end users  , optionaly you can connected to an sms provider  , like https://www.octopush.com/api-sms-documentation/

you can build your sms gateway based on that api and plug your users to your sms gateway